# Leaflet - Popup layers in same location

Tags: leaflet, popup, layer

I have a map with the layer control layer, where each option is a bus line. If I mark two lines, and both pass in the same location, I can only get the information from the layer above, in the onEachFeature event. How do I show in a popup the information for all layers that are below the selected one? Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am also trying to implement the same feature.

Comment: @gis I saw this site https://www.fernandoquadro.com.br/html/2019/05/08/representando-linhas-de-onibus-no-leaflet/ but for what I needed it didn't work.